# Word VBA of CrossReference

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am using Word 2010 and want to create a VBA script to insert a cross-reference.

I often insert a cross-reference of table numbers and figure numbers. So, I want to firstly show a dialog to answer which label, table, or figure to be inserted. Here, for example, I will type `Figure`. Then, I want to show another dialog to answer the table number or figure number. I will type `5`.

Then, "Figure 5" should be inserted.

The VBA script I wrote is as follows:

```
Public Sub CrossReferrence()  
' To Insert Cross Reference  
'  
Dim reftype As String  
reftype = InputBox("The label to be inserted "Table" or "Figure" = ?")  
Dim refnum  
refnum = InputBox("Table number or Figure number = ?")  
If refnum <> "" Then  
    Selection.InsertCrossReference _  
        ReferenceType:="reftype", _  
        ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _  
        ReferenceItem:=refnum  
End If  
End Sub
```

It seems that the Macro stops when it comes to the If sentence. 
Please correct the Macro.

Comment: I solved it by myself.　ReferenceType:=reftype (no need "") This worked.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you for sharing the snippet. Just want to reference to the VBA method: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa212260(v=office.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

ReferenceType:=reftype

No need to use "". This worked.